# Unable to re-deploy war file in Tomcat 8.0.26

Tags: apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee, war, web-deployment

I created a war file and deployed on Tomcat(8.0) server. It access shared library files from Apache's lib folder. When i try to deploy my war again it shows (Out of memory error: Permgen Space) error. The application starts only when i restart Tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

Can you increase the amount of memory given to Tomcat?  My thought is that both applications are in memory for at least a little time and Tomcat is running out of memory.

Common ways of increasing Tomcat memory are either modifying bin/catalina.sh (or .bat) and hardcoding something like CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx2048m or setting CATALINA_OPTS in your environment before you startup Tomcat.